# Flash will not load images if it is embedded into a website

Tags: html, flash

I have just finished making a flash banner in Fl5 and have embedded it into my website.

I can view it in my browser by going directly to the file however when it is embedded the photos will not load. The images it loads has to be in the same directory as the .swf file and as i stated it clearly works when going directly to the file but not once it has been embedded.

If someone else has had this issue or knows how to fix it, please help me

Thank You.

the directory of where the flash file can be found is:

http://tinyurl.com/6q5pu79

the website address is:

http://tinyurl.com/7x7nzz3
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths you specify for the images in your code are by default relative to the HTML file where they are embedded (if you go directly to the swf, they're relative to the swf). You can fix that by using the `base` parameter when you embed.

Add a param in your HTML:

```
<param name="base" value="banner" />
```

... inside both `<object>` elements.

That tells FlashPlayer that relative paths in your code are relative to the "banner" directory rather than the directory where the HTML file is.

Comment: I tried this and could not make it work :-( any other suggestions?

Comment: Try again with my edits - I accidentally called your folder `swf` instead of `banner`. ;-)